# Empty ggplot graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I'm trying to plot a ggplot graph of a time serie dataframe. However, the resultant plot is empty.

```
nombre_ERA5 <- format(as.Date(gsub(x=names(ERA5_prom),pattern="X",replacement="",fixed=T), format = "%Y.%m.%d"),format="%Y-%m-%d")
names(ERA5_prom) <- nombre_ERA5 
#plot(ERA5_prom[366:731],type="l")

df <- data.frame(names(ERA5_prom))
colnames(df)[1]<-c("Fecha")
df$Valor <- ERA5_prom

ggplot()+geom_line(data = df,aes(x=Fecha,y=Valor))

df
Fecha    Valor
1   2015-01-01 284.0547
2   2015-01-02 283.5696
3   2015-01-03 284.7942
4   2015-01-04 287.0302
5   2015-01-05 286.3637
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure its empty and not just a solid line near the bottom? try custom scaling your y axis to be more close to your Valor values

Comment: Your y axis scale is far too large to display information in the -11 order of magnitude. And as RAB mentions it is a straight line as your Valor values are constant at -9.246e-11. That dark line at the bottom is what that is.

Comment: I think you may also have changed the dates into factors in `Fecha`. Check what `str(df`) gives you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this one, please specify group

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Fecha,y=Valor, group = 1)) + geom_line()+geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Putting the `aes` and `data` arguments inside the `ggplot` versus the geom shouldn't change anything. This isn't substantially different from what the OP already posted.

Comment: @Camilie We only have to add group = 1 into the ggplot or geom_line aes(), that was missed previously

Comment: Why? That doesn't change the y-axis scaling or the fact that the x-axis is most likely encoded as a factor